# Soap request to https via proxy

Tags: php, soap, https, proxy

I want to call a SOAP method via proxy on PHP. WSDL path is https://eaisto.gibdd.ru/common/ws/arm_expert.php?wsdl

I tried like this:

```
$url = 'https://eaisto.gibdd.ru/common/ws/arm_expert.php?wsdl';

$soap_params = array(
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
        array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'SNI_enabled' => false
            ),
            'http' => array(
                'proxy' => 'tcp://54.193.18.175:80'
            ),
        )
    ),
    'connection_timeout' => self::CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,
    'proxy_host'     => '54.193.18.175',
    'proxy_port'     => '80'
);

$gibdd_client = new SoapClient(self::GIBDD_URL, $soap_params);
$get_data_request = $gibdd_client->GetCardByVin(array());
```

But it doesn't work. Error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://eaisto.gibdd.ru/common/ws/arm_expert.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://eaisto.gibdd.ru/common/ws/arm_expert.php?wsdl"
```

When I used http://eaisto.gibdd.ru/common/ws/arm_expert.php?wsdl instead of https://eaisto.gibdd.ru/common/ws/arm_expert.php?wsdl it works properly. How I can send a SOAP request to https via proxy?

I tried with

```
'ssl' => array(
    'SNI_enabled' => false,
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
),
```

But this doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$streamContext = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => true,
        'cafile' => <path to the CA file>,
        'local_cert' => <path to your PEM cert>,
        'local_pk' => <path to your private key PEM file>
    ]
]);

$options = [
    'proxy_host' => '<your proxy host>',
    'proxy_port' => <your proxy port>
    'proxy_login' => '<your proxy login>',
    'proxy_password' => '<your proxy password>',
    'stream_context' => $streamContext
]

$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```

I did this successfully on PHP5.4, but i wonder if it still works in modern versions of PHP: there use to be a bug that may be back : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50489

Also note that error messages won't be helpful.
E.g. I am getting *error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol* when the proxy rejects the authentication with *HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden*... Weird and unhelpful...